# How do I put both PCA and a keras classifier into an sklearn pipeline and do a grid search CV?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, pipeline, pca, gridsearchcv

I am trying to do a grid search CV operation on a keras NN with PCA beforehand. To this end, I have constructed a pipeline consisting of the PCA step then the keras estimator using the sklearn wrapper. However, one of the things I want to search through is n_components of the PCA, which means that the input size of the neural net needs to be variable and dependent on the number of features selected in a previous piepline step.

Below is my code to create a NN which I have put into a keras wrapper

```
def create_model(learning_rate=0.01, activation='relu',Input_Vector_Size=34,
                 neuron_number=10,dropout_prob=0.1):
    # Create an Adam optimizer with the given learning rate
    opt=Adam(lr=learning_rate)
    
    
    # Create your binary classification model  
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(neuron_number,input_shape=(Input_Vector_Size,), 
                    activation=activation))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_prob))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')) #output layer
    
    
    # Compile model with your optimizer, loss, and metrics
    model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model
```

Which I put into a pipline using

```
#%% Create a Pipeline with the Keras_Classifier and PCA
pca=PCA(n_components=0.9)
NN=KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model,verbose=0)
# Define the parameters to try out
pipeline=Pipeline([('pca',pca),('NN',NN)])
params = {'pca__n_components':[0.8,0.85,0.9,0.95],
          'NN__activation': ['relu', 'tanh'], 
          'NN__neuron_number': [10, 15, 20], 
          'NN__dropout_prob':[0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3], 
          'NN__learning_rate': [0.1, 0.01, 0.001]}
```

However I'm a bit stuck on what to set as the param for Input_Vector_Size as this will be dependent on how many features PCA has selected.

So, is it possible to make a pipeline parameter (here, the Input_Vector_Size) that is dependent on a parameter in a previous step of the pipeline (here, the number of features selected by PCA)?

(Note: I realize that one option around this is to just have an autoencoder in my NN and vary the compression, however I was hoping to do PCA specifically)

Comment: if u don't define any input_shape in the first layer of your sequential model?